# View is not updating in ONLY some cases

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, data-binding

This method is used to add thousand separators for a input. it will remove non numeric characters and then pip will add separators in the view.
but when the input is something like " 12hy " it doesn't work.If the is input is like " 12hy6 " it will give the output as expected like " 126 ".

**What am I not understanding?** when in the debugging actually the model changes as expected.BUT the view is same.

In the model code is like this ->

```
public onInputChange(event: string , id: any): any {

        switch (id) {
            case 'mgtFeeFromValue': {
                this.mgtFeeFromValue = this.changeText(event);
                console.log(this.mgtFeeFromValue);
                break;
            }


            default: {
                this.loggerService.logError('Cannot find case in switch statement line : 730');
                break;
            }
        }
    }

public changeText(str: string): any {
        if (typeof str === 'string') {
            const formattedNumber = parseFloat(str.replace(/\D/g, ''));
            return formattedNumber;
        } else if (typeof str === 'number') {
            return  str;
        }
    }
```

In the view - >

```
<input
    [ngModel]="mgtFeeFromValue | number:'1.0-5'"
    (ngModelChange)="onInputChange($event ,'mgtFeeFromValue')"
    maxlength="8"
    class="reset-input-style w-100 text-right"
>
```

Here's a working example - >

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g5l4ra?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: can you please share working demo ?

Comment: Yeah sure ill add it
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g5l4ra?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: if input is "12hy", output should be "12", right ?

Comment: yes it has to be

Comment: I have found a alternative way to block non numerical inputs and to add thousand separators 
here's the stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g5l4ra?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

try this solution.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [DecimalPipe]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  public mgtFeeFromValue: any;

  constructor(private _decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {}

public onInputChange(event: string , id: any): any {
  console.log(event, id)

        switch (id) {
            case 'mgtFeeFromValue': {
                let temp = this.changeText(event);
                this.mgtFeeFromValue = this._decimalPipe.transform(temp, '1.0-5');
                // console.log(this.mgtFeeFromValue);
                break;
            }

            default: {
              console.log('Shit happens');
                break;
            }
        }
    }


  public changeText(str: string): any {
        if (typeof str === 'string') {
            const formattedNumber = parseFloat(str.replace(/\D/g, '').concat(' '));
            return formattedNumber;
        } else if (typeof str === 'number') {
            return  str;
        }
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<input
    type="text"
        [(ngModel)]="mgtFeeFromValue"
        (keyup)="onInputChange($event.target.value ,'mgtFeeFromValue')"
    >
```

check [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-decimal-pipe)

Do let me know if you still face issue.

Comment: Yeah it;s working thank you very much !
But there is a small issue with that implementation. 
we can see that string replacing happening.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but it works if you wrap your code in `setTimeout` (Shown below), Hope someone explains this.

```
public onInputChange(event: string, id: any): any {
setTimeout(() => {
switch (id) {
        case "mgtFeeFromValue": {
          this.mgtFeeFromValue = this.changeText(event);
          console.log(this.mgtFeeFromValue);
          break;
        }

        default: {
          console.log("Cannot find case in switch statement line : 730");
          break;
        }
      }
}, 100)
}
```

*One more thing you have to use 2-way binding for updating view to template and vice versa

Comment: It's not working 
Also I can't use two way binding cause I want to use number pip in the view :(